# Watir - file_field.exists? comes up as false even though there is an upload form on the page

Tags: ruby, watir

I am looking at a web page with an overlay that contains a Choose File/Browse etc button
Below is a snippet from the page

```
<form name = "form1" method = "post" action = "UploadPhoto.aspx?PhotoUploaderFor=1" id = "form1" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<div>...</div>
<div class = "popup-form photoUploader">
 <div class = "group data-row">
  <label>...</label>
  <input type ="file" name = "FileUpload1" id = "FileUpload1" class = "browse_file">
```

Watir has file_fields which can handle file uploads
I've tried on the test site (www.tinypic.com) and the controls work fine there

```
b.file_fields.exists?
```

will return true

However, on the page i'm looking at with the snippet above,

```
 b.file_fields.exists?
```

returns false

I thought it might be because of the form, so I also tried

```
b.form(:name => "form1").file_fields.exists?
```

Which also returns false
If i try to access the button itself directly, this also returns false

```
b.element(:xpath => "//input [@name = 'FileUpload1']").exists?
```

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT

The form is inside an iframe

```
<iframe id="Step1_Banner1_Popup_Photo_Photo_Iframe_PhotoUploader" class="photoUploaderFrame" scrolling="no" src="../MSReport3/UserControls/UploadPhoto.aspx?PhotoUploaderFor=1">
#document
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD CHTML 1.0 .....">
  <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
   <code from above goes here>
```

Comment: Using your snippet locally, `browser.file_field(:id => "FileUpload1").exists?` returned true.  Is there possibly a frame on this page?

Comment: Hi @orde,
Thanks for taking a look.  There is an iframe created a few steps above.  

    <iframe id = "Step1_Banner1_Popup_Photo_Photo_Iframe_PhotoUploader" class = "photoUploaderFrame" scrolling = "no" src="../MSReport3/UserControls/UploadPhoto.aspx?PhotoUploaderFor=1">

Comment: @orde thanks for the heads up.  Even though I could find the form inside the iframe, without referencing it, I guess that doesn't hold true for all the other elements.

b.frame(:id => "Step1_Banner_Popup_Photo_Photo_Iframe_PhotoUploader").file_field.exists? returns true

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I'm posting the solution from the comments so that (hopefully) this question can be tagged as answered.

The overlay is within a frame, and it's necessary to specify the frame via method-chaining.  For example:

```
b.frame(:id => "Step1_Banner_Popup_Photo_Photo_Iframe_PhotoUploader").file_field.exists?
```

Comment: You have a typo (```file_fields``` should be ```file_field```)

Comment: @Jeff references `file_fields` in his question.  Both `file_field` and `file_fields` methods should work in the above example.

Comment: No, it won't work as ```file_fields``` returns ```FileFieldCollection``` and it doesn't have ```#exists?``` method.

Comment: Thx @p0deje.  I made the edit and meant to follow up (but got distracted).  Assuming a page has `<input type ="file">`, the result of `browser.file_fields.exists?` would be `undefined method exists? for #<Watir::FileFieldCollection:0x312a3c8> (NoMethodError)`